# How To add Two Variables To An Ahref

Tags: variables, href

i have two variables 
one is $wallet
the second is
$link
i liked to make something like that:

```html
<div>hi' <?php echo $userRow['user_wallet']; ?>&nbsp;<a href="$link$wallet">Check Your Bitcoins </a></div>
```

How Can I Do This?

Comment: What's wrong with what you've posted? Is it not working? what are the **exact** variable names? Does your posted sample code use these *exact* names?

Comment: Yes This Is The Real Names Variables used there

Comment: well i like to pull the user_wallet row from database to a variable $wallet and set the $link variable $link ="https://faucetbox.com/check/" in this case is to check they own wallet so after i liked to join the two variable to do the link

Answer (score 0):

i finally i tank so i discover how to do..

```html
$user_points = $row['user_points'];
$wallet = $row['user_wallet'];
$link = "https://faucetbox.com/check/";;
$resultlink = $link.$wallet;
<a href="<?php echo "$link"; ?><?php echo $userRow['user_wallet']; ?>" >Check Your Adress</a>
```